# PHP, While in While

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm going to try to tell you what I'm about to do with this code.

I'm creating a table with in de first column the names of the users followed by the amount of days in the current month (each day in a column).
Now I'm trying to create select options in each row/column to choose a value from.

Here's my code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="addtable">
<tr>
<td class="tabletitle">Personeelslid</td>
<?php
do{
    echo "<td class=\"tabletitle\">".$i."</td>";
    $i++;
} while ($i<=$dagen);
?>
</tr>
<?php
while($row_pers = $mysql->fetch_array($result_pers))
{
    $j=1;
    if ($color == _COLOR_WHITE){
        $color = _COLOR_GREY;
    } else {
        $color = _COLOR_WHITE;
    }
    echo "<tr class=\"trborder\">";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"".$color."\">".$row_pers['pers_naam']."</td>";
    while ($j<=$dagen){
        echo "<td  bgcolor=\"".$color."\">";
        ?>
        <select name="naam_id" id="naam_id">
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <?php
        while($row_shiften = $mysql->fetch_array($result_shiften))
        {
        echo "<option value=\"".$row_shiften['shift_code']."\">".$row_shiften['shift_code']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php
        echo "</td>";
        $j++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

The current result gives my all I want except the select options are only showing up on 1 place. Is it possible to cache it or rewrite my code to make it work?

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the options output inside of a string, and generate that once.  Then reference the stored options for each row in the output table:

```
<?php
while($row_shiften = $mysql->fetch_array($result_shiften))
{
    $options += "<option value=\"".$row_shiften['shift_code']."\">".$row_shiften['shift_code']."</option>";
}
...
while ($j<=$dagen){
    echo "<td  bgcolor=\"".$color."\">";
    ?>
    <select name="naam_id" id="naam_id">
    <option value="test">test</option>
    // add in the options generated once
    <?php echo $options; ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    echo "</td>";
    $j++;
}
```

Also, you will not want all your `<select>` to have the same id, so you should append some sort of unique suffix.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies.

I've used your solution to fix this problem. A small error in your code was: $options += should be $options .=

I've also generated unique id's for the select by using the person id, month and day.

Answer (score 0):

We probably will need more code, for example: table structure and queties. It looks like if you are trying to combine data from two tables, and it is much more common to do that with a JOIN query. (e.g. http://mysqljoin.com/ a site dedicated to this topic entirely)

Good luck!

Comment: This really should be a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. New to the habits of this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have "used up"  your $result_shiften so you can't use it anymore. You need to copy it to another var, somewhere at the top of your script:

```
$options = "";
while($row_shiften = $mysql->fetch_array($result_shiften))
{
    $options += "\m<option value=\"".$row_shiften['shift_code']."\">".$row_shiften['shift_code']."</option>";
}
```

then just use echo $options underneath

```
<option value="test">test</option>
<?php echo $options; ?>
...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following your request properly, but it looks like you need a more unique name/ID for the SELECT entities. Right now you have a variable number of SELECT tags all using the same "name" and "id" ("naam_id").

Change those to variables based on the result from your `$row_pers` result. Alternatively, you can use `$j`, but that may not help you once you've submitted the form and are looking to process the inputs.